# drop down-list selected-index color must remain constant after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am developing a website in asp.net. There is a drop down-list and a button. In the drop down-list there are HTML errors. when the user selects a HTML error and then clicks the button, there will be a alert message. I'm changing the color of the selected index of drop down-list using the java-script, so that the user must not select the same error,but when the user clicks the button, the color disappears.

I don't know to use Ajax

Any help is appreciated

Comment: would you paste some code please ?

Answer (score 1):

You are losing the value because of PostBack. Whay you need to do is.

1) When you are changing the color of the selected index of drop down-list using the java-script, keep this index in the hidden field.
2) When the submit button is clicked, you will have to fetch this hidden value and change the color of dropdownlist index from the codebehind, this will you will persist the color of dropdown.